# Eclipse - generated method parameters final

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

Can Eclipse make parameters for generated methods (overwriting, implementing interface, etc.) final, and if so, how?

If I'm not mistaken, IntelliJ had an option for it. I could not find something similar in Eclipse.

I have become accustomed to making parameters final manually, but I am hoping for an automatic solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible.  I've not found any option to customize it under `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates or under Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates`.

Anyway, Eclipse 3.3+ comes with "save actions", an alternative mechanism for doing that. Under `Preferencens > Java > Editors > Save` actions it is possible to configure "additional save actions". On the code style tab there is an option to automatically add final modifiers to private fields, method parameters and local variables.

Comment: Would be nice if there was also an option to make functions final.

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed in the "save actions". Check this blog post for a screenshot: [Eclipse and the automagical final](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/2007/12/05/eclipse-and-the-automagical-final/)

Comment: Your link was awesome. Been trying to do this in the new code templates for the last half hour for 10 seconds of work!

Answer (score 1):

There's cleanup options under 'Project' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Java Code Style' -> 'Clean up', but these can be applied after code has been generated...